# Excel Index Match with or function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an `INDEX` `MATCH` formula that includes 3 criteria with the 3rd criteria being an `OR` statement. This is for a payslip application where I would like the employee info to come from a lookup of the employee static data.

[image: Screenshot of table]

I currently have the following working as 3 criteria (I have removed the `INDEX` part to make it easier to read):

```
={MATCH(1,($M$2= EMPLOYEES[NAME])*($N$2>=EMPLOYEES[Date])*(($N$2<=EMPLOYEES[EndDate])),0)}
```

If the first 2 criteria return `TRUE`, but the date is blank, it will return `#N/A`. I would ideally like the 3rd criteria to be an OR statement so that the date

When I change the last criteria to an `OR` statement as shown, it returns the wrong result. It ignores the second criteria and the 3rd criteria with the `OR` statement, so effectively returns the position of the first employee that matches the `EMPLOYEES[NAME]`.

```
={MATCH(1,($M$2=EMPLOYEES[NAME])*($N$2>=EMPLOYEES[Date])*(OR(($N$2<=EMPLOYEES[EndDate]),(EMPLOYEES[EndDate]=0),0)))}
```

Am I using the wrong syntax here or are `OR` statements not compatible with the `MATCH` function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATED EXAMPLE
[Updated sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzhiK.png)

I would expect P5 to return a value of £40.00 as the input date is greater than the date in C7. Or have I misunderstood.?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can easily put an OR on the last two criteria but it should be OR, not AND/OR.

Comment: Do you want to guard against N2 being blank as well?

Comment: Thanks Jeeped for the quick response. I am not worried about N2 being blank as will be controlled by data validation in another workbook.

Comment: Re your comment "You can easily put an OR on the last two criteria but it should be OR, not AND/OR." I am not sure that I understand. How do I show that in my formula please.?

Comment: OR/AND statements are not compatible with **array formulas** as they have an internal array processing built-in. Nested IFs or boolean statements multiplied against each other are the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Info column from the sample table in the following image, use this in P2 then fill down.

```
=INDEX(employees[info], AGGREGATE(15, 7, (ROW(employees[info])-ROW(employees[#Headers]))/((employees[name]=M2)*(employees[date]<=N2)*SIGN((employees[enddate]=TEXT(,))+(employees[enddate]>=N2))), 1))
```

(Structured table references are always a little wordy)

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that. I almost understand the formula, but not quite enough to make it work in my scenario. I have taken your example above and amended it slightly to show realistic info that I am looking to use, but am not getting the right data fed back when I have two names the same in the name column. I have attached the example to my original question, as couldnt work out how to attach and example to a comment. Hopefully something simple.?

Comment: What kind of date is 29/02/2017?

Comment: Excuse me - I'm an idiot. That works like a charm now. Thanks Jeeped for the education - that really is a complex formula.! I will now break it down in order to understand it completely. Your patience is much appreciated. Julian